# What all parameters can we take into account when comparing different quantum programming languages

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-algorithms, q#

I am planning to write a paper which compares Qiskit and Q# in the following circuits/algorithms

- Bell circuits
- Controlled swap to test similarity of two registers
- Phase kickback between two qubits
- Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm
- Grovers algorithm
- Simons algorithm
- Shors algorithm (slightly advanced for me)

What all parameters apart from time and space complexity can I take to compare these languages

Comment: As @Chris Granade already said in his answer, such comparison will have very limited value. Instead, consider using the things that have impact on developer experience such as: simulators performance, available debugging options, quality of documentation, community size, ..etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as with classical computing, we don't expect that in quantum computing the choice of a programming language will have a direct effect on the time and space complexity of most algorithms. That is, while C, Python, Rust, and Swift are all very different programming languages, quicksort is a $O(n \ln n)$ algorithm in all of them. Rather, classical languages tend to be compared on the basis of whether they are low-level or high-level, how easy they are to work with, what safety they provide the programmer (e.g.: it's more difficult to segfault in Python or Rust than in C), and so forth.

---

If you're interested in more resources comparing quantum languages, you may find https://www.nature.com/articles/s42254-020-00245-7 helpful. I also have a look together with Sarah Kaiser on Q# coming out soon that you may find interesting as well: https://bit.ly/qsharp-book

Comment: I think something which can differ from language to another is the amount of "simulation" of a real quantum physical computer vs having the same effect as a quantum computer ? I have no real idea how these really work but they were used as arguments for te languages

Comment: @BrockenDuck: Simulation time is also fairly separable from languages, as it turns out. For example, the first design principle for Q# is that the language should be independent from what target programs run on (https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-language/#design-principles), meaning you can swap between different simulators and devices while keeping the language and libraries the same.